# react-bootstrap - how do use it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am only recently working with react, I am a complete newbie. Now I have integrated a login function. This seems to work with `react-bootstrap` shapes and bottons.

A line in my `Login.js` file is

```
import {Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel} from "react-bootstrap";
```

To my question:
Where can I get the react bootstrap files (need it local)?
Where do I have to drop it?

Comment: Do you have Node package manager: `npm install`?

Comment: What do you mean by "need it local"? Did you save react-bootstrap to your package-json (with something like [`npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)), or is this code just copied from somewhere without installing react-bootstrap?

Comment: Did you follow the [getting started guide](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/getting-started/introduction/), and at what step did you have trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Where can I get the react bootstrap files (need it local)?
A: Install Bootstrap using terminal

Where do I have to drop it
A:Inside of node_modules folder of your project

Answer (score 0):

Where can I get the react bootstrap files (need it local)?
A: Install Bootstrap using terminal 
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/getting-started/introduction/

Where do I have to drop it
A:Inside of node_modules folder of your project